# Logic behind Standalone Precompiled graphics

Tags: standalone, preview, groupplots, externalize

I want to compile my expensive graphics to a PDF such that I can integrate the files in my main document. I am using pgfplots and groupplots for that purpose. So let's say I have two graphics looking like that:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{ticks=none}
\begin{groupplot}[group style={group size= 4 by 1,horizontal sep=0.1cm},
    height=.25\textwidth,
    width=.25\textwidth,
    title style={yshift=-1.5ex}]
\nextgroupplot[title={f1}] 
\addplot[blue, ultra thick] (x,2*x*x);
\nextgroupplot[title={f2}] 
\addplot[blue, ultra thick] (x,x*x);
\nextgroupplot[title={f3}] 
\addplot[blue, ultra thick] (x,x*x);
\nextgroupplot[title={f4}]
\addplot[blue, ultra thick] (x,x*x);
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Then the spacing works fine, everything adapts to the textwidth perfectly. However, if I externalise this graphic via standalone, nothing with regard to spacing seems to make sense anymore. For example the following two files have different lengths although every plot in the groupplot is assigned a width of \textwidth divided by number of plots in one row.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\begin{document}
\textwidth=7in
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{ticks=none}
\begin{groupplot}[group style={group size= 4 by 1,horizontal sep=0.1cm},
    height=.25\textwidth,
    width=.25\textwidth,
    title style={yshift=-1.5ex}]
\nextgroupplot[title={f1}] 
\addplot[blue, ultra thick] (x,2*x*x);
\nextgroupplot[title={f2}] 
\addplot[blue, ultra thick] (x,x*x);
\nextgroupplot[title={f3}] 
\addplot[blue, ultra thick] (x,x*x);
\nextgroupplot[title={f4}]
\addplot[blue, ultra thick] (x,x*x);
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\begin{document}
\textwidth=7in
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{ticks=none}
\begin{groupplot}[group style={group size= 3 by 1,horizontal sep=0.1cm},
    height=.25\textwidth,
    width=.33\textwidth,
    title style={yshift=-1.5ex}]
\nextgroupplot[title={f1}] 
\addplot[blue, ultra thick] (x,x*x);
\nextgroupplot[title={f2}] 
\addplot[blue, ultra thick] (x,x*x);
\nextgroupplot[title={f3}] 
\addplot[blue, ultra thick] (x,x*x);
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

How can I make this right? [Here](https://www.overleaf.com/read/dgvfdtcmkbkk) is the example in overleaf.

Comment: `\textwidth` makes no sense in standalone as it adapts its size to the content. Have you had a look at the `external`ization library of TikZ (and `pgfplots`)? That will offer you to output the figures you are actually producing.

Comment: I had a look at the more standard ways of externalizing but it didn't work. I even asked the overleaf support team for help and everything they came up with was to use the standalone option. Why on earth is this so complicated?

Comment: Well, the external library normally does work as expected (given that you actually run it with shell escape which Overleaf might not allow you to). Otherwise you have to reproduce your layout with standalone meaning you would have to copy the important bits and pieces of your preamble into your standalone graphics (or using a file that you could input).

Comment: The problem here is that `pgfplots` doesn't have the most intuitive setup with regards to scaling. When you set the `width`, to 5cm, `pgfplots` sets the width of the axis box itself to 5cm - 45pt. The 45pt is a rough estimate for the width required for ticklabels and axis labels, and there is (currently) no attempt made to more accurately determine that width. If you add `scale only axis` to the `axis` options, the `width` and `height` specify the size of the axis box itself, so labels come in addition. This is documented in the manual.